# How to use prop in html class

Tags: reactjs

```
<textarea class="form-control quiz"{item.title}"" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
```

in this example i want to add item.title prop with quiz class

I want to add prop with quiz class so how should I concatenate this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
<textarea className={`form-control quiz${item.title}`} id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use template string :

```js
<textarea className={`form-control quiz${item.title}`} id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3">
```